# How to calculate and save correlation coefficients in matlab?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, accelerometer, feature-extraction, pearson-correlation

I am working on pedestrian step detection (acceleration data), I want to calculate **statistical features** from my filtered signal. I have already calculated some and now i want to calculate **correlation coefficients** .

My data is of 1x37205 double. I calculated features using for loop with moving window `size=2samples` and 50% overlap of previous window. Below I am attaching the code I tried with to calculate `corrcoef`.

Now i want to check if it is the right way to calculate and also want to save the out put. I am unable to understand well that how to save all corrcoef's. Could some one guide me or provide any code help in matlab or how i can save?

```
%%Here M is mean and V is variance i already calculated from filtered data
    for i=window:length(M)-window
    C = corrcoef(M(i-window/2:i+window/2),V(i-window/2:i+window/2))
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [corrcoef documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/corrcoef.html#f80-999628-R) you can see that the output is a 2x2 matrix.

The easiest way then to save all the coefficients would be to initialize your matrix C outside of the loop and then just assign values at each iteration.
Perhaps something like

```
C = zeros(2, 2, length(window:lenght(M)-window));
for i = window:length(M) - window
    C(:, :, i) = corrcoef(M(i-window/2:i+window/2),V(i-window/2:i+window/2));
end
```

Even better, you can also see that the output of the corrcoef function is structured like this:

```
[1, c1;
 c2, 1];
```

where c1 and c2 are the actual coefficients.
So you could also do:

```
C = zeros(length(window:lenght(M)-window), 2);
for i = window:length(M) - window
    temp = corrcoef(M(i-window/2:i+window/2),V(i-window/2:i+window/2));
    C(i, 1) = temp(1, 2); % "c1"
    C(i, 2) = temp(2, 1); % "c2"
end
```

**EDIT TO ANSWER TO COMMENT**

To implement a sliding window with any size and with any overlap, you might want to change the indexing:

```
wdwSize = 2;
overlap = 0.5;

C = zeros(length(1:wdwSize*overlap:length(A)-wdwSize*overlap), 2);

for i = 1:wdwSize*overlap:length(A)-wdwSize*overlap
    window = i:i+wdwSize - 1;
    temp = corrcoef(M(window), V(window));
    C(i, 1) = temp(1, 2); % "c1"
    C(i, 2) = temp(2, 1); % "c2"
end
```

In your case wdwSize*overlap is an integer, but you might want to be careful for a general combination of window size and overlap.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is working well. But i just want to know one thing that am i doing right or wrong? what i want to do is to calculate corrcoef over moving window with window size=2samples and 50% overlap of previous window. Looking for the kind response. @Matteo V

Comment: @muhamamdhammadmalik edited my answer to make sure the sliding window was correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot dear for the kind help. Got your point. The only difference in yours and mine algo is, i kept first value always 0 while in yours code it is starting from 1. @Matteo V

Comment: The way you had implemented actually created a window of size 3 (`i - window/2: i + window/2` contains `i - 1`, `i` and `i + 1`).

Comment: Alright, so what if i change it to the following code and i want to keep first value at 0. @Matteo ,    for i=window:length(M)
    C = corrcoef(M(i+1-window:i),V(i+1-window:i))
    end

Comment: That would work, but keep in mind that Matlab only works with positive indexes, i.e. M(0) will alway return an error. Anyway, I believe this would be outside the scope of your initial question, so consider accepting this answer if it solved your initial problem.

Comment: alright, thanks for kind help.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, this function reurns a matrix.
If the only problem is literally "how to save this data", you can store it in a cell array.

```
numSamples = length(M)-window;
result = cell(1, numSamples);
for i=window:numSamples
    result{i-window+1} = corrcoef(M(i-window/2:i+window/2),V(i-window/2:i+window/2))
end
```

Remember that you can retrieve data from the cell array just as you would do with a list, but instead of using "result(i)" you need to use "result{i}".

Comment: thanks for your answer. i not just want to save but want to calculate too, i am not sure sure if i am doing right or wrong. what i want to do is to calculate with window size=2samples and 50% overlap of previous window. And as you mentioned to use result{i}, it is taking too long time and giving '[]' as output. @user1407368

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I just realised that you start from "window", not from 1. I edited  the code to fix the mistake.

Comment: Thanks but it is still giving the same as output. The one mentioned by Matteo is working.